# Rails 4 + append_view_path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to use dynamic path in my controller in rails gem.

I've added to

```
module MyGem
  class FooController < Config.controller
    before_action ->{ append_view_path "app/views/my_gem/#{wizard_name}" }
...
```

and in views I need to specify path like

```
app/views/my_gem/#{wizard_name}/my_gem/foo/some.erb
```

is in Rails some way, to cut the relative path of gem namespace, and get lookup path like?

```
app/views/my_gem/#{wizard_name}/some.erb
# or
foo/bar/some.erb
```

Thank you!

UPD:

I understand, that there is way with disabling `isolate_namespace` in `Engine`, but I believe, that it is not best and only option.

UPD2: For Rails4 this idea was very useful https://coderwall.com/p/p_yelg/render-view-outside-of-a-controller-in-rails-4

Comment: I have trouble understanding exactly what you want. Could you please give an example of your views?

Comment: view content does not matter in this question, question is only about views lookup path.

Comment: So, what does your `view_paths` looks like, how should it look like, and how did it look like after using `isolate_namespace` ?

Comment: In rails 5 you can just call the render method on your controller. It makes rendering a view in background jobs, etc. quite easy: here is a nice blog post. http://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/01/08/rendering-views-outside-of-controllers-in-rails-5.html So down the road when you upgrade you might be able to simplify things a bit.

Answer (score 1):

The Devise gem has a way of adding views lookup path by overriding the _prefixes method:

```
class DeviseController < Devise.parent_controller.constantize
  include Devise::Controllers::ScopedViews

  # Override prefixes to consider the scoped view.
  # Notice we need to check for the request due to a bug in
  # Action Controller tests that forces _prefixes to be
  # loaded before even having a request object.
  #
  # This method should be public as it is is in ActionPack
  # itself. Changing its visibility may break other gems.
  def _prefixes #:nodoc:
    @_prefixes ||= if self.class.scoped_views? && request && devise_mapping
      ["#{devise_mapping.scoped_path}/#{controller_name}"] + super
    else
      super
    end
  end

end
```

Can this be applied to your use case?

See source:
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise_controller.rb

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you should only override the partial views or the functions from that gem, do not load from the gem lib like this, because when deploying to the real server it will raise many troubles for you to debug and improve.

Answer (score -1):

You could make your how render method that reads an arbitrary file, interpret the ERB and render it as an HTML page for instance.

```
ERB.new(File.read(Rails.root.join('foo', bar', 'some.erb'))).result(binding)
```

By passing `binding`, the template will have access to the all the variables in the current context.

See ERB docs for more details: http://apidock.com/ruby/ERB

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your gem is an engine, you should be able to simply call `render :some` in the engine. If the app has a view called `<gem_name>/<controller_name>/some.html.erb` it will be used.

Also, you can provide a version of that view in your gem that will be used if the app does not yet provide one.

If you need the `wizard_name` to also be looked up, I think the best way to do that would be to move that portion of the view path to the to the end where you are calling render.

So in your gem's controller you would write `render "#{wizard_name}/some"` and it would look for that view both in our app's `app/views/<gem_name>/<controller_name>/<wizard_name>/some.html.erb` and in your gem's `app/views/<controller_name>/<wizard_name>/some.html.erb`.